# How to get rid of "Sprint call has possible formatting directive" from go-vet

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

```
stmt := fmt.Sprint("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(last_date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS last_date FROM `my_db`.`my_table` WHERE rowId=", rowID)
```

This statement generates a warning in VSCode from go-vet. ""Sprint call has possible formatting directive %d".  I understand why go-vet generates a warning, but there is nothing wrong with the code: %d is a part of the sql statement.

What is the best way to get rid of this warning?

Comment: I'm compelled to point out that this line of code is very dangerous - you almost certainly have a SQL injection vulnerability if you are formatting SQL using Golang's tools. In this case if rowID is an integer type, it's likely safe, but I would be very concerned if I read a line like this in a code base.

See: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection

Answer (score 3):

To prepare a statement that can possibly contain Go formating directives, you can use `Sprintf` like this:

```
stmt := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(last_date,'%s-%s-%s') AS last_date FROM `my_db`.`my_table` WHERE rowId= %d","%Y", "%m", "%d", rowID)
```

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/PXHTOJRPtaq) is a working example.